# How can I identify the source of a cyclic dependency in C++

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me how I can identify which classes are causing the cyclic dependency issues that I am seeing?

Comment: If stones are arranged in a circle, at which stone does the circle start? :-)

Comment: If you post some code up we may be able to help you...

Comment: Look up here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem

Comment: @Sujay: the "diamond problem" you link to has nothing to do with cyclic dependency - that's an ambiguity issue.

Answer (score 2):

The typical problem with a circular dependency occurs in such a situation:

```
// foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "bar.h"

struct Foo { void use(Bar); };

#endif // FOO_H

// bar.h
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

#include "foo.h"

struct Bar { void use(Foo); };

#endif // BAR_H

// bar.cpp
#include "bar.h"
```

What happens when the preprocessor works on `bar.cpp` is the following:

```
// bar.cpp

// #include "bar.h"
// BAR_H is not defined
// #define BAR_H

// #include "foo.h"
// FOO_H is not defined
// #define FOO_H

// #include "bar.h"
// BAR_H is defined, skip
// #endinclude "bar.h"

struct Foo { void use(Bar); }; // ERROR: Bar is not defined

// #endinclude "foo.h"

struct Bar { void use(Foo); }; // OK: Foo is defined

// #endinclude "bar.h"
```

This could, potentially, be detected using preprocessor tricks, to have a nice message at compile. However it is slightly complicated and adds to the include guards cruft that is already necessary... so most of the times, you just try to compile, and if it does not, and you cannot make sense of the errors, you can always get the preprocessed file using a compiler switch (-E on gcc).

Now, to get into the preprocessor tricks. The issue as we can see is that even though `BAR_H` is defined, the file has not been included, yet.

The solution is to prepare another guard, to signal the fact that the whole file has been processed, and emit an error if ever we are in a situation when only one of the two guards is defined.

It looks like so:

```
// bar.h
#ifdef BAR_H
#ifndef BAR_H_2
# error "Cyclic inclusion involving bar.h"
#endif // BAR_H_2
#else

#include "foo.h"

struct Bar { void use(Foo); };

#define BAR_H_2
#endif // BAR_H
```

As you can see though, it doubles the cruft already necessary for header guards, for a relatively low frequency error. So it is usually not deemed worthy.

Answer (score 1):

1. Forward declare classes and structures in your headers
2. Remove includes from your header files

Perform these two steps on all your headers to identify circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

guard them like so:

```
#ifndef HEADER_FILE_IDENTIFIER
#define HEADER_FILE_IDENTIFIER

/* ...declarations... */

#else
#error "multiple inclusion"
#endif /* HEADER_FILE_IDENTIFIER */
```

(where `HEADER_FILE_IDENTIFIER` is obviously a unique identifier)

Comment: @Justin: Smart... except that headers are *meant* to be included multiple times. What you want to detect is whether they are "re-included" *before* having been totally included.

Comment: @Matthieu M. this is how i guard my headers. most headers, if necessary, should be included exactly once. cassert and pseudo-generation blocks (headers *intended* to be included multiple times) are the common exceptions to this. i know it's not common, but it forces one to sort out dependencies correctly (while also reducing the number of files to open).

Comment: @Justin: I must admit I don't really see the point. Most preprocessors are smart enough to cache whether or not they need to reopen a file -- effectively treating header guards as the `#pragma once` directive.

Comment: @Matthieu M. VS2008 doesn't: http://www.bobarcher.org/software/include/results.html

Comment: @Justin: Ah too bad... definitely an easy optimization as the include guard scheme is so frequent... I prefer standard conforming compilers though, so doesn't affect me much :)

Comment: @Mathhieu M. doesn't affect me much either. i keep my dependencies well managed :)